# Is there any way in which we can add data in file using python in increment order

Tags: python, hash

I am trying to add data in file "example.txt" using python. Every time I run the "Test.py" file I want to add data in file in increment order.
Below is the code I tried

```
i = 0
for i in reversed(range(0,20,1)):
    i = i+1
    value = ("hash%s"%i)

index = 0

with open("Test.txt", "r") as f:
   contents = f.readlines()

contents.insert(index, value)


with open("Test.txt", "w") as f:
   contents = "".join(contents)
   f.write(contents)
```

The out put I am getting is:

```
hash1hash1hash1
```

Expected output:

```
On 1st run of code output should resemble: hash1
On 2nd run of code output should resemble: hash2
On 3rd run of code output should resemble: hash3
```

Comment: -1 since you changed the wanted output after a few people already gave a correct answer to the output you wanted first. Please try to give the correct info from the beginning, otherwise people are wasting their time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces (nearly) your *Expected output* in three runs:

```
with open("Test.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.seek(0)
    value = len(f.readlines())+1
    f.write(f"On {value}. run of code output should resemble: hash{value}\n")
```